# Pre-populated database in ionic 2

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have some static data and I have created a SQLite database file using **DB Browser for SQLite** for same. Now want use that SQLite database file in my Ionic 2 application.

I looked into https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/read-existing-sqlite-database-file-and-load-data/94167/10 post but didn't get a solution.

Can anyone please help me!!!

Ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

Global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

Local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.0.2
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.3
```

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872960/where-to-place-pre-loaded-db-file-in-ionic-2-rc0

Comment: Any update? Dis you able to solve it?

Comment: No, I am unable to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using

**[cordova-sqlite-ext](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext)**

for install,

**`cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-ext --save`**

> A Cordova/PhoneGap plugin to open and use sqlite databases on
>   Android/iOS/Windows with REGEXP (Android/iOS) and pre-populated
>   databases (Android/iOS/Windows)

```
var db = null;
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
  db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'demo.db', location: 'default'});
});
```

**IMPORTANT**: Like with the other Cordova plugins your application must wait for the `deviceready` event. This is especially tricky in Angular/ngCordova/Ionic controller/factory/service callbacks which may be triggered before the deviceready event is fired.

Here's detailed example for this.

**[Ionic Framework App With Pre-Filled SQLite DB](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/deploy-ionic-framework-app-pre-filled-sqlite-db/)**